# Use webassets scss filter on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sass, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The Flask-Assets/webassets `scss` filter works fine on my local machine, because I have SASS installed. The EC2 instance in my Elastic Beanstalk application does not, so it gives an error.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 732, in decorated_view
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/decorators.py", line 194, in decorated_view
  return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/python/current/app/app/frontend/prep.py", line 427, in deliveries_outstanding
  ('created_at', 'Added'),
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
  context, ctx.app)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
  rv = template.render(context)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
  return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/opt/python/current/app/app/frontend/templates/prep/_model_list.html", line 4, in top-level template code
  {% from "macros/stickers.html" import render_sticker %}
File "/opt/python/current/app/app/frontend/templates/prep/_master.html", line 16, in top-level template code
  {% assets "css_prep" %}
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/ext/jinja2.py", line 181, in _render_assets
  urls = bundle.urls(env=env)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 685, in urls
  urls.extend(bundle._urls(env, extra_filters, *args, **kwargs))
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 647, in _urls
  *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 504, in _build
  force, disable_cache=disable_cache, extra_filters=extra_filters)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 390, in _merge_and_apply
  filters_to_pass_down, disable_cache=disable_cache)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 429, in _merge_and_apply
  kwargs=item_data)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 272, in apply
  return self._wrap_cache(key, func)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 219, in _wrap_cache
  content = func().getvalue()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 252, in func
  getattr(filter, type)(data, out, **kwargs_final)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/filter/sass.py", line 141, in input
  self._apply_sass(_in, out, os.path.dirname(source_path))
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/filter/sass.py", line 122, in _apply_sass
  shell=(os.name == 'nt'))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Right now, I am using `pyscss` instead, but its implementation is flawed and sometimes generates incorrect css (e.g., it messes up the the SASS version of Bootstrap).

Is there anyway to force my Elastic Beanstalk app to install SASS on all instances?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get sass installed by sshing into the instance and running:

> gem install sass

To get this to install on all new instances add this to a config file in your .ebextensions directory

```
packages:
  rubygems:
    sass: ''
```

The empty quotes specify to install the latest version. Add a version number there if you want a specific version.

More info is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages

Comment: This is not a full-proof solution as Elastic Beanstalk automatically kills and creates new instances without warning.

Comment: I was going to try adding the command to the .ebextensions config file. I'll update my answer with the results.